# Database table with foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I have a table with a column that is an ID to either table T1 or table T2.
Is it a good idea to add an extra column that indicates if that ID is from T1 or T2, or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably be happier with two columns: one a foreign key to T1, the other a foreign key to T2.

Comment: Hm, good idea, simple is always best. I'll give it a bit more time though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the context of the application.  There are a number of cases where an architecture like the one you are using would be very dynamic.  However, to use this efficiently with user interfaces for CRUD operations, you'd want views of the data limited by the indicator column you mentioned.  Really, the merit there is that when you want to add table 3, you can just add another indicator value.

If the application you are working on is fairly simple or will use a number of known data entry screens and will not automatically support the data in a new table, then I agree with the other answer that has been posted, suggesting separate foreign key columns.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse. Good advice. In this particular case the DB is quite simple, this being possible the only more "complicated" part. And there is almost no chance that there will ever be a 3rd table.